# Hibernate is multiple @EmbeddedId supported?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

Is it possible to have multiple @EmbeddedId composite keys defined for a @ManyToOne relationship between classes? Example:

Entity 1

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name="pk.method", column=@Column(name = "http_method", nullable = false)) })
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.operation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", nullable = false)) })
public class Action {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ActionId pk = new ActionId();


}

@Embeddable
private class ActionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne private Operation operation;
    private HttpMethod method;

}
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides
// Need to override the embedded if attributes of the Action entity inside the UserActionId class
public class UserAction {

    @EmbeddedId private UserActionId pk = new UserActionId();
}

@Embeddable
private class UserActionId implements Serializable {

    // How to provide a @JoinColumn for the Action.pk composite key (action.pk.authURL) and @Column for (action.pk.httpMethod)
    @ManyToOne private Action action;
    @ManyToOne private User user;


}
```

Is this possible? I have tried but keep getting a Hibernate error saying that the FK must have the same number of columns as the ActionId pk.